# BuildFire.JS WebRTC - Cannot access camera and mic

Tags: javascript, webrtc, jitsi, buildfire

I am trying to start video chat app inside the widget builder in buildfire.js using WebRTC. I am getting the following error message:

```
69a6d1ba-ed1f-4f05-8835-7f70168acf27:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
bt {gum: {…}, name: 'gum.permission_denied', message: 'User denied permission to use device(s): audio, video', stack: 'Error\n    at new bt (https://meet.bingewave.com/li…bingewave.com/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js:2:509715'}
gum:
constraints: {video: {…}, audio: {…}}
devices: (2) ['audio', 'video']
error: DOMException: Permission denied
[[Prototype]]: Object
message: "User denied permission to use device(s): audio, video"
name: "gum.permission_denied"
stack: "Error\n    at new bt (https://meet.bingewave.com/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js:2:269189)\n    at https://meet.bingewave.com/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js:2:509715"
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

I'm not being prompted for access to my camera or microphone and the error message says permission has been denied, how do I allow buildfire.js to access camera and mic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register device requirements of your plugin.json file. This will alter they way your app is built.

Here is the documentation you need
https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/features-list/

Comment: I am having the same issue. According to your docs, I don't see camera service on that page, but I do see this camera service here: https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/camera . But this is not what I want to do as its for taking picture vs enabling the video for webrtc. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

SDK 1.65.2 has now support for native permission requests for Android and iOS

Check the following new SDK functions:

https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/camera/#isauthorized https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/camera/#requestauthorization