# WebRTC Not Working On BuildFire - No Camera or Mic Access

Tags: webrtc, buildfire

I am having an issue with WebRTC that relates to these issues:

- [BuildFireJS IFrame Allow Access To Camera and Mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889424/buildfirejs-iframe-allow-access-to-camera-and-mic)
- [BuildFire.JS WebRTC - Cannot access camera and mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876590/buildfire-js-webrtc-cannot-access-camera-and-mic)

So there is no feature request for the camera in feature list here: https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/features-list

And I have added the camera script to the bottom of my widgets script:

```
<script src="../../../scripts/buildfire/services/camera/camera.js"></script>
```

But when I open my open the BuildFire previewer on both my Android and IPhone, nothing works. Now whats being implemented inside the webpage is a url like below but inside an iframe:

https://widgets.bingewave.com/webrtc/65fc7098-d7ee-41fa-98e9-2bcd48f8f95d

Its standard Webrtc. How can I get WebRTC working in BuildFire? Which means how can I get camera and mic access working in a BuildFire app?

Answer (score 0):

No feature request is needed as Camera is a built-in feature